# Is there an easy way that we could assist a group with updating their IP Range Restrictions with our list of valid IPs?

Tags: user-management

We have over 100 profiles and they didn’t add all the ranges to all the IPs.  Because of this they are now having issues with users not being able to log in.  I was hoping we could offer up a quick win to help them with the update vs. manually updating 100 profile IP ranges.

Comment: What do you mean by a group ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata of profile to update this info.

In profile metadata find loginIPranges tag and you can add your IP ranges.In fact copy paste to all profiles one by one and save metadata.

To edit metadata you need eclipse or mavensmate or any IDE that supports force.com

Comment: Thank you Mohit,

Is there any reference example/ Documentation where we can get the process on how exactly to do this?